# how to free my singly linked list program?

Tags: c, if-statement, malloc, singly-linked-list

I have 2 questions regarding my code:

1. Why isn't `struct node *a,*b;` working in `create()`? I get this message: `b is used but it is not initialized`. It is also not working in the `if` statement.
2. If we use `malloc()` in normal program we can use free like this -> `free(variablename);`, but how do I go about freeing a singly linked list?

Here's my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<malloc.h>

struct node
{
int d;
struct node *next;
}*start=NULL;struct node *a,*b;

void create()
{
    a=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    printf("Enter the data : ");
    scanf("%d",&a->d);
    a->next=NULL;

    if(start==NULL)
    {
        start=a;
        b=a;
    }

    else
    {
        b->next=a;
        b=a;
    }
}

void display()
{

    struct node *a;
    printf("\nThe Linked List : ");
    a=start;

    while(a!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%d--->",a->d);
        a=a->next;
    }
    printf("NULL\n");
}


void main()
{
    char ch;
    do
    {
        create();   
        printf("Do you want to create another : ");
        ch=getche();
    }

    while(ch!='n');

    display();
    free(a); // i don't know is this crt?
}
```

Comment: You have to manually free each element. You are pretty much on your own when it comes to memory management.

Comment: When you ask why some code doesn't work, you should show the code that doesn't work instead of describing it in words. Also, write what error you get and what line you get it on.

Comment: @interjay can you please edit my code sir with free() ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must free each element of your list individually. Each slice of memory that has been allocated by `malloc` must be freed with `free`.

Instead of calling `free(a)` at the end of your program, call `freenodes()`.

```
void freenodes()
{
    struct node *a;
    a = start;

    while(a != NULL)
    {
      struct node *freenode = a ;
      a = a->next;
      free(freenode) ;
    }
}
```

Comment: @R.A: BTW you should modify your functions so they take as argument the head of the list instead of using the global variable `start`.

Comment: @MichaelWalz: Perfect explanation.

Comment: if i add your code at the end of my program it will works fine and freed previous allocated malloc memory right ?

Comment: you have created a new function for free and call the allocated values of a and then freed the memory by this new function correct? @michael..

Comment: @r.a.: obviously yes.

Comment: @michael thankyou very much, can you give me your mail id or facebook username? i will ask my doubts about c and c++,

Comment: @r.a. if you have questions about C and C++, stackoverflow is the right place. Post your questions here.

Answer (score 0):

Free link list as follows.

```
void freeList(struct node* head)
{
   struct node* tmp;

   while (head != NULL)
    {
       tmp = head;
       head = head->next;
       free(tmp);
    }

}
```

Comment: can u please edit my code with free ? really i don't understood your words, i am basically a beginner sorry jayesh

Comment: @Jayesh: calling `free(a)` or `free(start)` will free only the first element of the linked list (the element pointed by `a` ou by `start`)

Comment: @MichaelWalz It's my mistake not `free(start)` but `freeList(start)`